# How to use Imported Vb.net files

Tags: vb.net

In my application i have to search to an external directory for a file
Example;

```
ExternalFile = Application.StartupPath & "\NecessaryFile.dll"
```

How do i use imported files
(Such as in Projects > Properties > Resources) in the application?

Update:
How would i change this

```
Dim File = Application.StartupPath & "\Necessary.dll"
```

To this

```
Dim File = Me.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("WindowsApplication1.NECESSARY.dl")
```

As to have the files required by the application part of the program, so that
I don't need to put unnecessary files in the same folder of the application.

Comment: How are you wanting to use them, are you trying to implement a plugin architecture? Need more info as it stands now question is to broad.

Comment: I'm wanting to inject a dll into a process, and to do so i have to end up putting the dll in the same folder as the compiled application, and i would rather have the dll integrated into to exe.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to paste your .dll file to the Project folder where bin folder is exists.

Then in IDE ( Integrated Development Environment) you have to right click on the Project in solution explorer and you have to click on Add Reference...

In Add Reference window, goto Browse tab.

In Brose tag you have to select your .dll ( which has been pasted earlier ) and then click on OK

Now, you can use .dll file coding by Importing NameSpace/class. To Import class you need to write following line in the top of any class of the application

Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Here, System.Data.SqlClient is just for example. You need to put respective name as per the .dll file provides.